# How to construct a Möbius loop using bezier curves

Tags: modeling, workflow, bezier-curves

I am a beginner and I am trying to construct a Möbius loop by using a bezier curve and then extruding, or whatever, with a circle. Can someone help me to achieve this in a step-by-step manner?

[image]

I know there are many ways to approach this and I wish to know as many of them as possible. I almost achieved it with the screw modifier but the two halves didn't fit together perfectly.

Comment: I think it is obvious that my Q. is different because it is a different form of moebius loop. See the images refered to in my Q. and contrast one with the other.

Comment: Could you upload pictures directly into your post by clicking the image icon while editing? Your profile pic on stackexchange currently appears blank to me, which is a good example of why it's better to embed images directly.. Thanks :) BTW, I could only find one likely image by googling your username (the one I've embedded into this question), so I wasn't able to compare your two questions to see how they differ.

Comment: Since this question is still flagged as CLOSED, I've tried to answer your question in that former duplicate thread [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/18954/696). you may go and have a look. FYI.

Comment: I agree with OP, it is a different kind of mobius, which requires specific answer.

Comment: Thanks Leon! I think that answers my question pretty well! But where you wrote "OP" did you mean LP for Leonardo Paradox

Comment: @Leonardo-Paradox op means original poster. No need to reopen this then since it has an answer and the other question is more general.

Comment: @Leonardo-Paradox I've updated the answer with a second method, which looks exactly what you want. (example file included)

Comment: @Leon can u give me more details. I'm stuck!

Comment: @Leonardo-Paradox OK. I've uploaded a [video](http://youtu.be/8npjdt0pBtQ). FYI.

Comment: That was good thanks, but I like it much better on paper. I cant download the video on my android tablet.