# Fit a narrow image on a strip

Tags: image

I have a very narrow image (e.g. 100px * 10000px), and I would like to fold it into an infinity symbol as a strip.

I found this model: http://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/3ds-mobius-strip/396686 It seems like all I have to do is put the image on each face. Is this something that can be done with Blender?

I also found the following model: http://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/3ds-mobius-strip/574060 Can I expect more/less trouble in doing this with this model than with the other one?

Extra question: would it be hard to create my own model to do this?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14824/3710

Comment: The second mesh isn't going to be any easier than the first to model since it is the same which has been given a shell. Start with creating the "simple'"Moebius and if you want you can add a 'solidify' modifier on it. For the texture you want either to unwrap your mesh or use the generated mapping, then you can apply your picture on it. Honestly I have tried to get the result you posted by playing around with curves but failed, I am not an expert in modelling and didn't put much time on it though, but you are attacking something quite difficult.Good luck mate.

Comment: If you follow the link that Poor posted and study Leon Cheung's answer you can get the shape you want. So save your money on that turbosquid model and try it yourself. After that the UV mapping is a bit tricky, but I had success with ripping the verts and UV unwrapping with "Follow Active Quads" using "Even" mode. This is a simplified how-to. I may or may not have time to give a detailed answer, but first wanted to let you know it's definitely possible.