# How do I make a celtic knot?

Tags: mesh

I have no idea how I'm supposed to tackle this, I've tried making a three-point star but after that I had no idea how to continue since a celtic knot has rounded edges.

[image]

Comment: There are quite a few Celtic knots, could you find an illustration to insert into your question?

Comment: Oh, sorry about that!

Comment: This celtic knot is a 2D illustration that doesn't necessarily translate to a coherent 3D shape. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99355/how-to-create-a-ribbon-wrapped-sphere/99358#99358 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14822/how-can-i-create-a-mobius-ring/18954#18954

Comment: could you please draw a picture of what you would like in 3D from your 2D picture?

Comment: If you want a 3D knot, you could take a look at the shipped Mesh: Extra Objects add-on > Torus Knots, and ask again if you have trouble tweaking type 1 into the shape you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is much too vague, how is your 2D shape supposed to be in 3D? I've tried a basic shape, tell me if that's what you want, I began with a half-circle as your knot is basically made with 3 half-circles:

[image]

Comment: Oh I'm really sorry for not really going into depth on how I would've liked it, but the way you did it really looks good. It's basically like yours so I am really thankful for your step-by-step guide.